# Postgresql - Split data from a column into two columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a small Porstgre database where I a have a table with several columns.
One of those columns contains data like this :
`test1 (80%)`
`test2 (21%)`
`test3 (40%)` etc ...

What I would like to do, is to be able to move that percentage to another column so the data will look like :

```
TEST_COLUMN | PERCENTAGE_COLUMN

test1       | 80%

test2       | 21%
```

etc...

Knowing that I have over 10k records, it would be helpful if there is a way to achieve this without having to move anything manually.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT  col ,TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '(\(\d+%\))$', '')) AS test_column
       ,(REGEXP_MATCHES(col, '(\d+%)\)$'))[1] AS percentage_column
FROM t;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8f4c8acfeb4d9d760d9d3fe6c52cf58d)**

Comment: I do like this answer as it's easier than the first one, and it worked well.
Thank sir

Answer (score 1):

you can just regexp it, or other text process, eg:

```
t=# with a(v) as (values('test1 (80%)'),('test2 (21%)'),('test3 (40%)'))
, p as (select v,string_to_array(v,'(') ar from a)
select v, ar[1],translate(ar[2],')','') from p;
      v      |   ar   | translate
-------------+--------+-----------
 test1 (80%) | test1  | 80%
 test2 (21%) | test2  | 21%
 test3 (40%) | test3  | 40%
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I didn't know we could do such thing and use regex in sql. Thank for your answer but looks a bit complicated tho.